# Updating Session ID to Test Name in Browserstack

Tags: ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am using Ruby/Capybara, and hooked up my test to `browserstack` but I see session ID in `browserstack` instead of the test name.  This is how I set it up:

```
Capybara.register_driver :browserstack do |app|
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
                               browser: :remote,
                               url: 'some/URI',
                               desired_capabilities: browserstack_capabilities)
```

How do I see the test name?

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding the "name" : "Some-name" capability in your capability set and that should work. For more details on capabilities, you may refer this link: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities

Comment: I tried that, it keeps the same name for the whole suite.  I want it to be dynamic and pick the name of the test from the spec.  This is something I have used before for rspec  @caps["name"] = ENV['name'] || example.metadata[:name] || example.metadata[:file_path].split('/').last.split('.').first

But not able to figure out for capybara.